# How to align vertically a matrix on nodes in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have prepared a series of illustrated tables for a technical brochure, and I have finally elected to use the option "matrix of nodes" of Tikz. I could not manage however to center (on the same vertical center line) the large labels such as "40" or "40C1" with the graphics above. How to do this? Strangely, the bottom labels, such a s "40 contacts #20" are perfectly aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [font=\sf,
mynode/.style={rectangle, text width = 4.5 cm, anchor=north, inner sep=0pt},
myheader/.style={rectangle, fill, color=blue!20, text width = 4.55cm, text=black, text centered, font={\Huge, \sf}, inner sep=5pt},
mylabel/.style={rectangle, fill, minimum height=10ex, color=black!10, text=black, text width = 4.55 cm, anchor=north, inner sep=5pt},
]
\matrix [column sep=0pt , row sep=0mm, align=center, draw, rectangle]
{
\node {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{40Insert.pdf}}; &
\node {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{40C1Inser.pdf}};
&\node {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{45Insert.pdf}}; \\
\node [myheader]{40};&\node [myheader]{40C1};&\node [myheader]{45}; \\
\node [mylabel] {40 contacts \#20 };
&\node [mylabel] {39 contacts \#20 \\ 1 coax or triax contact \#5 \\ or 1 contact \#10};
&\node [mylabel] {45 contacts \#20};\\
\node [mynode] {};& \node [mynode]{}; &\node [mynode]{};\\

\node [mynode] {};& \node [mynode]{}; &\node [mynode]{};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Why the `,` in the font key (it’s not a list)? Simply declare `font=\Huge\sffamily`.

Comment: I have edited the font declaration as you suggested.

Comment: It works. I wonder wether I should delete my question entirely or revert the code back to the mistaken one and close it. It is not clear to me however  why the declaration "font=\sf", at the "begin tikz picture" level is not sufficient to convert all fonts of the picture.

Comment: It would be better to revert your question to the erroneous version. Take a look at my updated answer where I have introduced some ways to tackle this problem differently.

Comment: I have reverted to the original mistaken version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font` key will not be processed like a list but the contents will simply be used before the node content. Simply declare

```
font=\Huge\sffamily
```

and the width of the comma will not be visible as horizontal space.

(As you may have noticed, I have also used the LaTeX macro `\sffamily` instead of the old TeX macro `\sf`, see [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/16595).)

On a semi-related note, take a look at the `matrix` library and the `matrix of nodes` option for the `\matrix` macro. With these you could simply use the node contents in the cells and define, say

```
row 2/.style={nodes=myheader}
```

---

If you want a cumulative `font` key define

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    add font/.code=\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}
\makeatother
```

You can now use `add font=\Huge` in the `myheader` style without repeating `\sffamily`.

Another idea is to use `\sffamily` directly in the `tikzpicture` environment, this can be done as a style, too:

```
\tikzset{set font to sf/.code=\sffamily}
```

or you define every picture to be in `\sffamily` with:

```
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at begin picture=\sffamily}}
```

### Code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\sffamily,
  mynode/.style={
    rectangle,
    text width = 4.5cm,
    anchor=north,
    inner sep=0pt},
  myheader/.style={
    rectangle,
    fill,
    color=blue!20,
    text width=4.55cm,
    text=black,
    font=\Huge\sffamily,
    inner sep=5pt},
  mylabel/.style={
    rectangle,
    fill,
    minimum height=10ex,
    color=black!10,
    text=black,
    text width=4.55cm,
    anchor=north,
    inner sep=5pt}
  ]
  \matrix [column sep=0pt, row sep=0mm, align=center, draw, rectangle]{
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{40Insert.pdf}}; &
      \node {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{40C1Inser.pdf}}; &
        \node {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{45Insert.pdf}}; \\
    \node [myheader]{40}; &
      \node [myheader]{40C1}; & 
        \node [myheader]{45}; \\
    \node [mylabel] {40 contacts \#20 }; &
      \node [mylabel] {39 contacts \#20 \\ 1 coax or triax contact \#5 \\ or 1 contact \#10}; &
        \node [mylabel] {45 contacts \#20}; \\
    \node [mynode] {}; &
      \node [mynode]{}; &
        \node [mynode]{}; \\
    \node [mynode] {}; &
      \node [mynode]{}; &
        \node [mynode]{}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Excellent. The code is much more readable and simple. I am going to change all calls for \sf, as suggested. I work on industrial documents, and virtually all fonts are sansserif